# Robolectric: interaction with dialog, created anonymously on view click

Tags: android, unit-testing, dialog, robolectric

I am new to robolectric as well as to testing android.* classes, and here is a problem: when user wants to specify his birthday, he clicks on a textview, which invokes a DatePickerDialog, and specified date is meant to be shown in the textview. Here is no any external links to the dialog. My code:

```
inputBirthDate.setOnClickListener(textView -> new DatePickerDialog(this,
            (view, year, month, dayOfMonth) ->
                    inputBirthDate.setText(
                            String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d/%d/%d", dayOfMonth, month + 1, year)),
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
            .show());
```

So, is there a way, without changing the original code, to get the dialog?

Comment: What do you mean to get the dialog? Did you check `ShadowDialog.getLatestDialog()`?

Comment: @EugenMartynov, I'll check it asap, thank you